# Setting up an Azure Static WebApp with an Api backend in a different region

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

We currently have a setup where our front end Angular App and our Api are hosted within an Azure Web App(which is in 32 bit Windows configuration) which connects to a db in AU region. We are thinking of moving the Front end out of the Web App into an Azure Static WebApp and Use a linux Docker container based Azure Web App for reduced pricing.
My question is, since Azure Static Web Apps are not available in AU region would there be any latency if I connected my AU based Azure Web App as an Api to the new Static Web App. Microsoft says Static Web App are non region based, but its only available in these regions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned:

- Static Web Apps are deployed globally
- Managed Functions are deployed regionally - but your scenario seems like it would not involve a managed Function App

Static Web Apps will not introduce any additional latency. If your user is in AU, they will load the frontend from a local data center with minimal latency. If you user is in the US, they will load the frontend from a different data center close to them. The latency of the calls to your API in AU are independent from the location of the Static Web App. If you deploy your application to a storage account in AU, you will have no relevant latency difference for users in AU.